# Missing python 3 API functions

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I was coding something at work and it seems that some C API functions provided by python are not working. I tried mainly the function that check types, for example:

```
import ctypes
python33_dll = ctypes.CDLL('python33.dll')
a_float = python33_dll.PyFloat_FromDouble(ctypes.c_float(2.0))
python33_dll.PyFloat_Check(a_float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    python33_dll.PyFloat_Check(a_float)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'PyFloat_Check' not found
```

Is there anything specific I need to do to use this function, or is it a bug?

docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/float.html?highlight=double#PyFloat_Check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyFloat_Check()` is [a macro](http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.3.0/file/1465cbbc8f64/Include/floatobject.h#l23). You will need to expand it manually and call the correct function instead.

Comment: Can you give me any other tip on how to do it?

Comment: I dont really know much about C. I would expect that to be a function. Anyway, if I call PyObject_TypeCheck it says it was also not found.